# Java RESTful API - JSON repsonse doesn't return some fields of an Object

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am a newbie when it comes to Java RESTful API's. My current problem is that the JSON response is not returning some fields. Here is what I mean;

I have some JSON code which will be used to create a user profile.

```
{
    "fName": "fUser",
    "sName": "sUser",
    "username": "helloUser"
}
```

I send this code to the appropriate `POST` method and afterwards I am expecting a JSON response. This is what I expect the response to be;

```
{
    "id": "003629d7-90ea-4139-9752-c9a8a21306f6",
    "fName": "fUser",
    "sName": "sUser",
    "username": "helloUser",
    "dateCreated: "Thu Jul 14 13:42:29 BST 2016"
}
```

Instead the JSON response that I get back doesn't have the `id` and `dateCreated` field. I was expecting them in the JSON response because I assign a value to these fields in the `Profile` constructor.

DatbaseClass.java

```
public class DatabaseClass {

private static Map<Long, Message> messages = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<String, Profile> profiles = new HashMap<>();

public static Map<Long, Message> getAllMessages() {
    return messages;
}

public static Map<String, Profile> getAllProfiles() {
    return profiles;
}
}
```

Profile.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Profile {

private String id;
private String username;
private String fName;
private String sName;
private Date dateCreated;

public Profile() {}

// Here I set the id and the dateCreated. Which is why I am expecting 
// the JSON response to show them.
public Profile(String username, String fName, String sName) {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.username = username;
    this.fName = fName;
    this.sName = sName;
    this.dateCreated = new Date();
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}

public void setfName(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

public String getsName() {
    return sName;
}

public void setsName(String sName) {
    this.sName = sName;
}

public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Profile [\nid=");
    builder.append(id + "\n");
    builder.append(", username=");
    builder.append(username + "\n");
    builder.append(", fName=");
    builder.append(fName + "\n");
    builder.append(", sName=");
    builder.append(sName + "\n");
    builder.append(", dateCreated=");
    builder.append(dateCreated);
    builder.append("\n]" + "\n\n");
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

ProfileService.java

```
public class ProfileService {

private Map<String, Profile> profiles = DatabaseClass.getAllProfiles();

public ProfileService() {}

public List<Profile> getProfiles() {
    return new ArrayList<>(profiles.values());
}

public Profile getProfile(String username) {
    if(!profiles.containsKey(username)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(
                "The profile " + username + " does not exist."); 
    }
    return profiles.get(username);
}

public Profile addProfile(Profile profile) {
    final String username = profile.getUsername();
    if(profiles.containsKey(username)) {
        throw new BadRequestException(
                "The profile " + username + " already exists.");
    }
    profiles.put(profile.getUsername(), profile);

    return profiles.get(profile.getUsername());
}

public Profile updateProfile(Profile profile) {
    if(profile.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    profiles.put(profile.getUsername(), profile);

    return profiles.get(profile.getUsername());
}

public Profile deleteProfile(String username) {
    return profiles.remove(username);
}
}
```

ProfileResource.java

```
@Path("profiles")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProfileResource {

private ProfileService pService = new ProfileService();

@POST
public Profile addProfile(Profile profile) {
    return pService.addProfile(profile);
}

@GET
public List<Profile> getProfiles() {
    return pService.getProfiles();
}

@GET
@Path("{username}")
public Profile getProfile(@PathParam("username") String username) {
    return pService.getProfile(username);
}

@PUT
@Path("{username}")
public Profile updateProfile(@PathParam("username") String username, 
        Profile profile) {
    return pService.updateProfile(profile);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{username}")
public Profile deleteProfile(@PathParam("username") String username) {
    return pService.deleteProfile(username);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see you calling that constructor anywhere.. You just use existing object.
You can also modify method as following:
`public Profile addProfile(Profile profile) {
    final String username = profile.getUsername();
    if(profiles.containsKey(username)) {
        throw new BadRequestException(
                "The profile " + username + " already exists.");
    }
    profile.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    profile(setDateCreated(new Date());
    profiles.put(profile.getUsername(), profile);

    return profile;
}`

Comment: Could be that the getters and setters are not properly formatted, try changing a few letters to upper and lower case.

Comment: Have you debugged using breakpoints?

Comment: @dty My problem went away but I didn't need to call the constructor anywhere. Is it right to assume that any fields not taken in the constructor should be set explicitly using the setter methods? Also in your last line of code you have `return profile`. Looking at it from a design point of view, is it not better to do `return profiles.get(profile.getUsername())`? So you know for certain that the profile is indeed in the `HashMap`. If it wasn't then the `put()` method would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Try outputting the Profile that you're allegedly returning on System.out prior to the controller returning it as JSON. Your code largely looks ok, but it would be good to know at which point the profile lacks the data you require. It should be there on instantiation. I think your controller may be throwing away. Worth checking the point of failure first. It may be worth making your Profile class Immutable, rather than having setters. That way, it's hard to make a mistake like this.

Comment: @TheRealRave Your problem was that your constructor with 3 parameters was never called anywhere. So naturally `id` and `date` fields was not initialized. In such case yes, you must set them via setters (in `addProfile()` for instance. I did not quite get the second question and why you think you should retrieve the element from the map instead of simple return.

Comment: What I meant was that if you get the element form the map then you know for sure it's there. So you'll know that `put()` executed successfully. Now lets say for example that `put()` failed to execute because of some reason. When you just do a simple return you wouldn't know that the element is actually not in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like object mapping mechanism provided by rest will call the default constructor, which is `public Profile() {}`, and use setter to put the username, fName, sName,
instead of calling `public Profile(String username, String fName, String sName)`.

You should set the id and create date in the service.